# Issue with using dotnet run as Entrypoint in docker image for c# webapi application

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was experimenting with docker and c# app, I noticed that ideally people are using both dotnet sdk image which is base image and dotnet runtime image.

My idea was why not just use dotnet sdk image to build the container? So i did this

Edit: here i copy my whole codebase to container and just do dotnet run in entrypoint.

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP2O4.png)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.414 AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./ ./testApp/

WORKDIR /app/testApp

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

I build this docker file and run my application with
docker run -d -p 5005:80 --name test test

Note: I'm running docker(docker.io) inside wsl2 ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Now im no longer able to access localhost:5005/home (which is a dummy controller which returns "welcome user").

When i try within wsl2 host using curl, I get the error as shown below.

curl localhost:5005/home
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

But within the container(using docker exec), if I do curl localhost:5005/home I'm able to get response.

When I try using this docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.414 AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./ ./testApp/

WORKDIR /app/testApp

RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.22 AS runtime

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/testApp/out ./

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "testApp.dll", "--url='http://localhost:5005'"]
```

using same docker build and run commands mentioned earlier, I'm able to access localhost:5005 on both windows host and on wsl2 host(using curl).

Pls can anyone help me understand what I'm missing here. why am i not able to access the port in 1st case. Is dotnet publish compulsory to access application inside container?

Comment: Why do you have different arguments in entrypoints of both docker files?

Comment: basically in 1st dockerfile i wont have any dlls with me since its just my raw code present on machine, so i do plain dotnet run in entrypoint when i run the container.

Ive added an image to help u understand, the whole codebase im taking into container and doing dotnet run.

In second i have the dlls with me and im using ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "testApp.dll", "--url='http://localhost:5005'"] here

Comment: Check the logs to see which port your app listens on. I doubt it's port 80. Only `aspnet` images listen on port 80 by default. The SDK image does not.

Comment: @Hans Thank you for your reply, based on your reply i checked this https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/tree/6da64f31944bb16ecde5495b6a53fc170fbe100d/src/sdk/6.0

i believe the sdk image does not expose any ports, i think this might be the issue im facing. I belive we need to use runtime image to be able to expose the port.

pls guide me if im wrong

Comment: @curiousDev EXPOSE is mainly documentation. You don't need to EXPOSE a port to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my Dockerfile in the project directory. Runs command `docker build -t test .` and `docker run -p 5001:80 test` works fine.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "./test.csproj"

WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "test.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "test.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test.dll","--server.urls","http://*/80"]
```

-------------------Update---------------------------
You could do following modification to make it work.
1.Modify the `launchSettings.json` and bind to port to `http://0.0.0.0:5130` or any port you like. Just notice if you bind to "http://localhost:5130" here, you also won't connect. It must be "0.0.0.0"
[image]
2.Expose the 5130 port in Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
EXPOSE 5130
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ ./testApp/
WORKDIR /app/testApp
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

3.Run `docker build -t test .` and `docker run -p 30002:5130 test` Then you could visit the page by port 30002.
[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply, but you didnt understand what im saying.

Lets say without docker if i want to run my c# app, i will do dotnet run on my host machine.

In my 1st dockerfile im doing the same in container now, ill run my code using dotnet run inside my container.

This is not working , is dotner restore and publish required compulsorily?

Comment: @curiousDev Seems should work, I will tell you later about my test. Generally SDK is too big for container.

Comment: my total image size is around 700MB, the container runs fine, but ports are not accessible.

Comment: @curiousDev I have made it work and modify the answer. You could have a try.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation on what steps to follow on this. Pls can you help me understand what was the issue before? if we gave localhost:port inside launchsettings.json, why is it not accessible? also could you pls let me know how you arrived at this conclusion.

Comment: @curiousDev I firstly enter into the container console and `curl localhost:5130` it works. So the problem turns to be why cannot connect to a port in the container from outside? There are many explains on web. Such as this one https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/xwfm08/why_do_i_need_to_specify_host0000_when_running_a/

Comment: Dear sir, thank you very much for your guidance on this, much appreciated, Ive understood a nice concept today. XD